# Associating two objects without nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Right now I have this:

```
resources :sources do
  resources :pages
end
```

And when I want to create a page for a particular resource, I use the following route helper:

```
new_source_page_path(source_id)
```

So in the controller I know for which source I need to create the page for.

My routes are getting really messy with deep levels of nesting, and I have decided to avoid doing the nesting. However my doubt is, if I have this:

```
resources :sources
resources :pages
```

In the new action of my PagesController, how do I pass or tell that this new object needs to be associated with that particular Source?

Comment: Pass in `source_id` in the params for page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the source_id as a GET param. Create your page#new links like this:

```
<%= link_to "new page", "/pages/new?source_id=#{source_id}" %>
```

Then in the page#new action assign that source to the page when you create the new page:

```
@page = Page.new
@page.source = Source.find params[:source_id]
```